# Angular RXJS Stopping a running interval from another method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Right now I have a method that starts and interval.

Here is the code:

```
interval: number = 5000;

start() {
    const myNumber = interval(this.interval);
    myNumber.subscribe(
      (number: number) => {
        console.log(number);
      }
    );
}
```

I want to add another method that will stop this interval:

```
stop() {
    // stop the myNumber interval
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to be able to restart it? I assume this would just be a case of calling `this.start()` again...

Comment: Yes, I need 2 methods ...start() and stop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `subject` or wrap the `subject` in `function`, and use `takeUntil` to stop

```
interval: number = 5000;
stop=new Subject();
start() {
    const myNumber = interval(this.interval).pipe(takeUntil(this.stop);
}

//stop the interval
stop.next(true)
```

Comment: I'm trying this: stopScanning() {
    stop.next(true);
  } and get this error: Property 'next' does not exist on type '() => void'

Comment: i don't have details about your code context, is it all in a class ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct...it's all in a class inside a component

Comment: then stop is a class property, you should use this.stop.next()